# Wordpress woo-commerce merge price before create grand total of product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created some attributes like length, service, color, sizes and also created variation for length & services.

when i view product all things are showing perfectly but actually i want when select any product length  and select  any services than price will be meagre.

i.e.  let us suppose

```
 select  length 10     = 1200 

 select services  Recomb  = `35`                                  
 $total= `1235`
```

How could this possible in woo-commerce ?

Is woo-commerce providing any plugin for this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to crate variable product and setup attributes then used that attributes for variation. create required variation and setup different price for each variation as per your requirement.

check below woocommerce docs for more info.
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: I already used variable product and also user variation , i have mention in my question also.

Comment: so just add different price for all variation. when user select variation from dropdown in product page price will auto change